# CSV, Grouping Products with their parent

Tags: csv, import, merge, openrefine

I've got a CSV file which will be used to import products into Woocommerce.

It's been generated from Magento and I am having severe trouble grouping parent products with their children (variations). The parent product has the Type "configurable" and the child "simple" and I cannot for the life of me find any unique identifier between the two of them which will allow me to import the children into their parent product.

I notice that each parent product SKU ends with 00, and goes up incremental for each of it's children, 01, 02, 03 and I've noticed that each parent product name is very similar to the child product, with the exception of the added variation attribute such as color etc. - Black, - Blue, - Red etc. being so similar in either SKU or Product name, would it be possible?

I'm thinking this has to be possible using OpenRefine.

Here are some example data, if you've got any idea about a method I can use to combine the two, please don't hesitate to elaborate.

```
ProductNo,Sku,Type,Product_name,Product_description,Price,CreatedDate,Status,categories
    32,VIS00500,configurable,"Spinner II Battery","Batterycapacity: 1650mah",
    33,Vis00501,simple,"Spinner II Battery - Black","Spinner II Battery - Black",0.0000,2014-10-02,Enabled,"Shop by Brand>Vision>Batteries and MODs",
```

And here is another, showing what I hope to achieve:

```
ProductNo,ParentID,Sku,Type,Product_name,Product_description,Price,CreatedDate,Status,categories
32,VIS00500, ,configurable,"Spinner II Battery","1650mah",14.1800,2014-10-02,Enabled,"Shop by Brand>Vision>Batteries and MODs",
33,Vis00501,32,simple,"Spinner II Battery - Black","Spinner II Battery - Black",0.0000,2014-10-02,Enabled,"Shop by Brand>Vision>Batteries and MODs",
```

Comment: Dying to try your solution at work tomorrow, I did manage to save your screen cast but I just noticed that you've deleted your reply. Please know that I am eternaly greatfull for help and that you took time to assist me. Deeply sorry that I did not give thanks any sooner.

Comment: I added a new answer based on your explanations on the Open Refine Google Group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you you've provided much more detailed explanations on the [Open Refine Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openrefine/N5JZpt918vI).

So, could you apply these operations (using "Undo/Redo") on [your dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ks-PfD5JIA8ewv0u6y2Kq6LO7wMCj6sY/view) and tell me if the result is right for you ?

```
[
  {
    "op": "core/row-reorder",
    "description": "Reorder rows",
    "mode": "row-based",
    "sorting": {
      "criteria": [
        {
          "errorPosition": 1,
          "caseSensitive": false,
          "valueType": "string",
          "column": "Sku",
          "blankPosition": 2,
          "reverse": false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "op": "core/column-addition",
    "description": "Create column isparent at index 2 based on column Sku using expression grel:if(value.match(/(.+00$)/).length() > 0, \"parent\", \"\")",
    "engineConfig": {
      "mode": "row-based",
      "facets": []
    },
    "newColumnName": "isparent",
    "columnInsertIndex": 2,
    "baseColumnName": "Sku",
    "expression": "grel:if(value.match(/(.+00$)/).length() > 0, \"parent\", \"\")",
    "onError": "set-to-blank"
  },
  {
    "op": "core/column-move",
    "description": "Move column isparent to position 0",
    "columnName": "isparent",
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "op": "core/column-addition",
    "description": "Create column parent at index 3 based on column Sku using expression grel:if(row.record.cells.Sku.value[0] != value, row.record.cells.Sku.value[0], \"\")",
    "engineConfig": {
      "mode": "row-based",
      "facets": []
    },
    "newColumnName": "parent",
    "columnInsertIndex": 3,
    "baseColumnName": "Sku",
    "expression": "grel:if(row.record.cells.Sku.value[0] != value, row.record.cells.Sku.value[0], \"\")",
    "onError": "set-to-blank"
  }
]
```

If you prefer human explanations :

1° Sort your column "Sku" as text by ascending order (a-z). Reorder rows permanently

2° Create a column "isparent" based on the column "Sku" using the following Grel formula, **and move this new column to the begining** :

```
if(value.match(/(.+00$)/).length() > 0, "parent", "")
```

3° Create a new column "parent_id" based on "Sku" using this Grel formula :

```
if(row.record.cells.Sku.value[0] != value, row.record.cells.Sku.value[0], "")
```

Comment: Awesome solution Ettore, thanks a lot for your time and assistance, it's just the solution I was looking for!